# mysql - set value of cell equal to value of cell in another row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query that generates a table for my vehicle tracking 'in' and 'out' times.

The problem is that the 'in' time is not the same as the 'out' time so seconds or minutes are lost in between.

Is there a way to set the 'in' time equal to the  'out time' from the previous row, even if I need to embed my current select inside a new select?

you will see on the image below that the first rows out time is `15:45:14` and the in time for the next row is `15:46:14`. so in this case a minute is `lost`

in reality if the vehicles has left one point, it is immediately on the road to the next point so I can set the `in` time equal to the `out` time of the previous row. This way, time is never `lost`

[image]

the sql for my query is:

```
select vehicle,InTime,OutTime from (select
      PreQuery.callingname as vehicle,
      PreQuery.geofence,
      PreQuery.GroupSeq,
      MIN( PreQuery.`updatetime` ) as InTime,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN( PreQuery.`updatetime`))as InSeconds,
      MAX( PreQuery.`updatetime` ) as OutTime,
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX( PreQuery.`updatetime`))as OutSeconds,
      TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX( PreQuery.`updatetime` )) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN( PreQuery.`updatetime`)))),'%H:%i:%s') as Duration,
      (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX( PreQuery.`updatetime` )) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN( PreQuery.`updatetime`))) as DurationSeconds
   from
     ( select
              v_starting.callingname,
              v_starting.geofence,
              v_starting.`updatetime`,
              @lastGroup := @lastGroup + if( @lastAddress = v_starting.geofence 
                                         AND @lastVehicle = v_starting.callingname, 0, 1 ) as GroupSeq,
              @lastVehicle := v_starting.callingname as justVarVehicleChange,
              @lastAddress := v_starting.geofence as justVarAddressChange
           from
              v_starting,
              ( select @lastVehicle := '',
                       @lastAddress := '',
                       @lastGroup := 0 ) SQLVars
           order by
              v_starting.`updatetime` ) PreQuery
   Group By
      PreQuery.callingname,
      PreQuery.geofence,

      PreQuery.GroupSeq)  parent

      where (InTime>  DATE_SUB('2013-03-23 15:00', INTERVAL 24 HOUR) or OutTime> '2013-03-23 15:00' ) and vehicle='TT08' order by InTime asc
```

The MySQL syntax is in depth so quite large but could be done on a much simpler query as well. like

```
select vehicle, intime,outtime from vehicletimes
```

My desired result is something like:

```
select vehicle, intime(outtime of row above),outtime from vehicletimes
```

The first rows in time can be as is and the last rows outtime can be as is. I just need to account for every second between the smallest in time and the largest out time.

Any help appreciated as always.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Don't you want to track the time while the vehicle is "in"? 2. Are you asking for the SQL to "report" that the the outtime is the same as the previous intime, or do you want to "correct" existing rows, or SQL to insert new rows?

Comment: The movement of a vehicle is sequential. so it logs it against a certain geofence or route. problem is that the vehicle sends update around every minute so the exact time for the new in is not known. for the sake of the project I am doing, setting the in time to the last out time is sufficient.

Comment: I have created a fiddle to play on, simplified MySQL example but same concept.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbf36/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you the latest in-time prior to *each* current out-time, for your existing records:

```
select
 vt.vehicle, max(qGetMaxOut.outtime) as intime , vt.outtime

from 
 vehicle_times vt

 inner join 
 (
    select vehicle, outtime
    from vehicle_times 

 ) qGetMaxOut
 on qGetMaxOut.vehicle = vt.vehicle 
 and qGetMaxOut.outtime <= vt.intime 

group by
 vt.vehicle, vt.outtime
```

The above query will also help you if you want to *insert* a new record, but need to find the previous in-time for a particular time (ie if you need to insert a new record who's in/out times are *prior* to the *latest* time - eg inserting a record that was somehow previously missed and where newer time entries have been added since).  If you need this scenario, let me know and I'll elaborate if you can't work it out from the above.

The join basically joins the table "back on itself" to provide another "copy", but limits the results in the "copy" to only those rows for the current vehicle in the main table, and excludes those rows from the copy where the vehicle's out-time is more recent than the current in-time from the main table.  This way you can do a MAX() over the copy, to find what the previous out time was.

I don't know your specific requirements, but I would recommend storing *the most accurate information you can*.  So if "sythensising" a value is just for cosmetic purposes on a few reports, I would leave the data alone, and tidy up the report, rather than loosing data that might come in handy down the track.  eg what happens if in the future, you suddenly have a requirement to tell your boss "how long are our vehicles 'in' and sitting idle for?"

But if you do just want to *insert* a new record with the *actual* out-time ignored, and replaced by the in-time from the *most recent* record, then this following query will find that value for you:

```
select
 vt.vehicle, max(vt.outtime) as intime

from 
 vehicle_times vt

group by 
 vt.vehicle
```

Have I missed your requirement?

Comment: Thanks Sepster, really appreciate the input. To clarify, I am just creating a 'timeline' report to show where the vehicle was at approximately what time. as such I need all time to be accounted for. I will still have the real accurate data if needed. I just output the query to a php array and play with it from there.

Comment: thanks again, awesome knowledge. I have tried this in a fiddle, not 100% correct. if you have a min would be appreciated. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbf36/7

Comment: @Smudger There you go mate, have a crack at that.

Comment: Legend, Thank you! I just need to play with some more examples to fully understand and appreciate it but working perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: @Smudger my pleasure mate, thanks for the accept.  Have added explanation about how/why the join works to the answer to try help you get your head around it.